# Configuring nginx-ingress for E2E tests

Tags: nginx, cookies, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a integration Kubernetes cluster in AWS, and I want to conduct end-to-end tests on that cluster.

I currently use Deployments and Services.

The proposed approach is to use Ingress and configure it to use cookie injection for ensuring access to web page that implements the following logic:

1. When *special* header is recognized in request -> allow the agent to enter the webpage (used for automated tests)
2. When *special* header is not recognized in request -> display popup for basic http authentication (used for normal users).

I also want to use a single entry point for both cases (the same url).

I've been browsing official documentation, but didn't find the specified use case, nor did I find any examples that might be close to what I want to achieve.

I'm interested if anyone has used similar approach or something that might be similar in use.

Many thanks!

Comment: Err, is there something stopping you from the "special header" being `Authentication: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` or whatever? I guess I'm not following the way that a special header is less sensitive than just assigning the agent login credentials?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like either [configuration-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) or a full-blown [custom template](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/custom-template/) may do what you want, along with the nginx [`if`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) and [`add_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) using something like:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ "My Sekrit Agent/666") {
    add_header Authentication "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=";
}
```